# Scrolling layout with Webview + LinearLayout in landscape mode

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a android UI with a webview in the upper part (2/3 of the screen) and a listview (last 1/3).

My webview has a fixed heigth set in the html code and only my listview can scroll in portrait mode.

But everything goes wrong in landscape mode: my listview totaly disappears while my webview can scroll

Here is my layout:

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/chartView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No value since : "
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:format="%s"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#017CBF"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="ALERT"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/alarmList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d6d7d4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_alert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
            android:text="No alert"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

I've tried to disable webview scrolling but it doesn't show the listview neither in landscape mode.
I've also tried to put my listview over my webview and I obvioulsy can see my listview. But my webview is shorted depending on the listview content and I can't scroll my full layout.

I'm a bit stuck now, so if you have an idea...

Thank you

Comment: U can use weightsum and layout_weight properties with android:layout_width="0dp" prop-value.

Comment: I knew this for the height prop_value but it doesn't seem  to be possible for the width.  I've applied to my webview and my linearLayout named alert_layout and i have an error "suspcious size: this will make the view invisible"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ScrollView which give you scrolling for you screen.
In there your example you use so many component. Take referance of this [Web Site](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/scrollview.php)

Comment: Obviously ever tried....  There is a listView in my linearLayout. If I use a scrollView, my listView will be always be set to its min height

Comment: ScrollView is allow only one direct child. so you have to take single Linearlayout and and put your code in this Linearlayout it works now.. And you have to run application in Emulator it does't show scroll in design view...

Comment: As I said....ever tried. Anyway, you can't compile if your scroolview has more than one children. Using scrollview this way, my layout displays only one scrollable row of the listview to see all the items. But thanks for the suggestion ;)